# Moving rows of data within pandas dataframe to end of last column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Python newbie, please be gentle. I have data in two "middle sections" of a multiple Excel spreadsheets that I would like to isolate into one pandas dataframe. Below is a link to a data screenshot.
Within each file, my headers are in Row 4 with data in Rows 5-15, Columns B:O. The headers and data then continue with headers on Row 21, data in Rows 22-30, Columns B:L. I would like to move the headers and data from the second set and append them to the end of the first set of data.

This code captures the header from Row 4 and data in Columns B:O but captures all Rows under the header including the second Header and second set of data. How do I move this second set of data and append it after the first set of data?

```
path =r'C:\Users\sarah\Desktop\Original' 
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.xls")

frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
  df = pd.read_excel(file_,sheetname="Data1", parse_cols="B:O",index_col=None, header=3, skip_rows=3 )

list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_)
```

[Screenshot of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsWum.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Just realized my question wasn't comprehensive; edited now.

Comment: The second part (B:L) will have NaN's in the last three columns - is that what you want? In this case you can use `skip_rows=[0,1,2,20]`

Comment: Thanks for responding! I can remove the NaNs later, but I think your solution doesn't quite allow me to move my headers and data from the second set and append it to the first?

Comment: I don't really understand it. Do you want to have two different sets of column names (headers) within one DF?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my data; hopefully this makes it more clear. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Why are you using pandas? Do you want to then import the complete dataset? This sounds like simply manipulating/formatting a spreadsheet and then saving.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your Excel files have the same number of rows and this is a one time operation, you could simply hard code those numbers in your `read_excel`. If not, it will be a little tricky, but you pretty much follow the same procedure:

```
for file_ in allFiles:
    top = pd.read_excel(file_, sheetname="Data1", parse_cols="B:O", index_col=None,
                        header=4, skip_rows=3, nrows=14) # Note the nrows kwag
    bot = pd.read_excel(file_, sheetname="Data1", parse_cols="B:L", index_col=None,
                        header=21, skip_rows=20, nrows=14)
    list_.append(top.join(bot, lsuffix='_t', rsuffix='_b'))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but I get an error: ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2', 'Unnamed: 5', 'Unnamed: 7'], dtype='object'). I also tried .merge instead of .join but I get the errror: MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Seems it's trying to merge data rather than just place it side-by-side as I'd like to .

Comment: No no... You need to use `join`, not `merge`... Take a look at its documentation for kwargs with "suffix" in them. I'm at the airport boarding a flight, else I would have edited my answer to include it. But I don't remember the kwargs off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file_,sheetname="Data1", parse_cols="B:O",index_col=None, header=3, skip_rows=3)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file_,sheetname="Data1", parse_cols="B:L",index_col=None, header=20, skip_rows=20)
# pay attention at `axis=1`
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```